# Start multicore background process from Django view

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I use Django to create a browser-based GUI for a multicore scientific computing library. The workflow is roughly as follows:

1. Press "run analysis" in browser.
2. Call django view.
3. In the django view, call the library. For simplicity let's say like that: `execfile('/path/to/library.py')`

Result: library.py runs only on a single core. However, when library.py is called from the python console (i.e. not from the browser) it uses multiple cores. Note that `library.py` contains all the multicore logic itself (using the multiprocessing module, as far as i can see).

Is it possible to have `library.py` use multiple cores, when started from django?

Comment: Django's development server is single-threaded. Have you tried a real server like gunicorn?

Comment: If you want parallel processing, you might try [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: Thanks, both comments pointed my in the right direction!