# Terminate asynchronous multiprocessing thread from gunicorn-based web session

Tags: python, django, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I use Django to create a browser-based GUI for a multicore scientific computing library, using gunicorn as a webserver (see also [Start multicore background process from Django view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31733676/5175389)). I call library functions as follows:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=library_function, args=())
p.start()
print("test")
```

The library function handles the multicore logic itself, so the whole point I am also using the multiprocessing module here is to enable the user to terminate the process (via `p.terminate()`). However, this is currently not working. My assumption is that I also need `p.join()` to terminate whatever is called by `library_function()`. The problem is that when I call `p.join()` after `p.start()`, the process seems to not run asynchronously anymore, i.e. in the example i.e. "test" is not printed immediately. However, asynchrony is definitely required in my use case.

Does anybody have a hint how to (1) run the process in the background and (2) still enable the user to terminate the process?

**UPDATE**

Following the comments by noxdafox this is my quick & dirty solution for now:

```
import psutil, signal, os, multiprocessing

# start process
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=library_function, args=())
p.start()

# stop process
for child in psutil.Process(p.pid).children(recursive=True):
    child.kill() # kill child processes
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL) # kill parent process
p.join() # kills parent zombie process
```

Comment: interestingly `for child in psutil.Process(os.getpid()).children(recursive=True): child.kill()` seems to work, although it's a somewhat scary solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `p.terminate()` sends a SIGTERM signal to the process. By default Python interpreter exits on such signals but there are cases in which it doesn't:

- The process is overwriting the default behaviour on SIGTERM signals. This might be set by Django framework itself for example (I don't know it's internals).
- The process is waiting for a C/C++ call to return and cannot react to SIGTERM signals.

`p.join()` blocks the caller until the child process does not end. It must always be called in order to clean up the expired child process. The reason why you loose the parallelism is due to the fact that you start the new process and wait until it's done.

You can use the [Pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) library if you want to spawn a task on a separate process and terminate it safely:

```
from pebble import process

@process.concurrent
def library_function( ... ):
    return

task = library_function( ... )
task.cancel()
```

More simply.

```
from pebble import process

task = process.concurrent(target=library_function, args=( ... ))
task.cancel()
```

**EDIT**: what you want to do is different and the way you're trying to do it at the moment is a bit dangerous.

Running a Pool of processes within a sub Process (from `multiprocessing.Process` and not `subprocess`) is not very optimal. Furthermore, terminating the process containing the Pool would lead to the leakage of all the worker processes.

From the [documentation of Parallel](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#parallel-reference-documentation) which is the implementation of the Pool of processes used under the hood.

> Interruption of multiprocesses jobs with ‘Ctrl-C’

To achieve that, you could send a SIGINT signal to the child process and see whether it actually works.

```
import multiprocessing, signal, os

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=library_function, args=())
p.start()

# stop the job    
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
p.join()
```

Comment: `pebble` seems to be really nice. The problem is however that it does not seem to support multi-core processing?

Comment: In which sense? It does support multicore processing if you use the process namespace functions.

Comment: You're right, the manual at least briefly mentions multicore support. However, when using `process.concurrent(target=library_function)`, the library_function uses only one core. By contrast, when using `multiprocessing.Process(target=library_function)` from the multiprocessing module, the library_function uses multiple cores.

Comment: `process.concurrent()` simply wraps `multiprocessing.Process()` in a more handy way, it uses it under the hood. If you want to spawn multiple instances of `library_function` just launch it several times. Or maybe I'm not understanding the problem?

Comment: The thing is that `library_function` has it's internal logic of spawning multiple instances of it's subfunctions (on which I have little influence apart from specifying the number of cores to be used). In other words, I intend to launch `library_function` only once and the multicore logic is done by the library.

Comment: Is library_function a publicly available lib? I could take a look at it. I don't see how `process.concurrent()` and `multiprocessing.Process()` could have such a different behavior as they are sharing the same implementation. Are you setting the `daemon` flag? Bear in mind that killing a process which has children might lead to unreleased resources.

Comment: Mmmh, strange indeed. I am not setting the `daemon` flag. The library_function is the first function in the following module: https://github.com/nilearn/nilearn/blob/master/nilearn/decoding/searchlight.py

Comment: .. which itself relies on the `Parallel` class from
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems that with this code the parent thread (`p.pid`) is indeed killed, but the child processes (having different pids) keep running in the background.

Comment: This is why I said it's a dangerous approach. The problem are the child processes which, if not properly handled by the underlying implementation, they will leak. Only solution which comes to my mind is re-implementing that function using the underlying implementation but with a regular, stoppable pool like the one Pebble provides.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but thanks for your generous help, I learned a lot! 

For now I'm using `for child in psutil.Process(THREAD.pid).children(recursive=True): child.kill()` and `os.kill(THREAD.pid, signal.SIGINT)`. However, this leaves behind the parent `THREAD.pid` as a zombie (`[python] <defunct>`).

Comment: Just join the parent process in order to collect its exit status and the zombie will be dead forever ;)

Comment: Np, glad you made it :)

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I would suggest for asynchronous task processing Celery would be better choice.

Using Celery you can enable users to revoke the tasks :

> > > result = add.apply_async(args=[2, 2], countdown=120)
> > >
> > > result.revoke()

By revoking, the celery work wont execute the task

Comment: Thanks, Celery would be my last resort, but for now I am trying to avoid the complexity involved.